# Low value on MAPE when using log CPI

Tags: accuracy, exponential-smoothing, mape

I'm trying to evalute my Holt-Winter model using MAPE (mean absolut percent error) and I'm getting a low value at 0.2% which seems a bit too low.

I'm using data on CPI from Belgium (per month) where I later use the log of CPI.

```
df_cpi <- read.csv("BELCPIALLMINMEI.csv", sep = ",")
ts_cpi <- ts(df_cpi1[,2], frequency = 12)
log_cpi <- log(ts_cpi)
df_cpi$log_CPI <- log(df_cpi$BELCPIALLMINMEI)

hw <- HoltWinters(log_cpi, seasonal = "mult")
hw.predict_f <- forecast(hw, h = 120, level = 0.95)

# where df_cpi2[,4] is logCPI in the data fram.
accuracy(hw.predict_f, df_cpi2[,4])
```

```
                      ME        RMSE         MAE         MPE       MAPE     MASE      ACF1
Training set -0.0004265488 0.004471188 0.003345786 -0.01037769 0.08063149 1.061585 0.4262202
Test set      0.0060551307 0.014094983 0.010424780  0.13261464 0.22684207 3.307680        NA
```

As can be seen, the MAPE value are very low. I'm wondering if there is a problem when using log of CPI when later on using MAPE? If i us the accuarcy() function on normal CPI i'm getting MAPE for Test set to be 1.51794 which seems to be more resonable.

Comment: They are not comparable: one is computed on the log scale and the other is not. If your goal is to minimize MAPE of CPI forecasts, then you have to back-transform the forecast from your log model and use that to compute MAPE on the untransformed CPI, regardless of if you transformed it to fit your model.

Comment: @ChrisHaug: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: Hi Chris Haug! My goal is not to compare them. I want to run log(CPI) and see what MAPE I will have. So using MAPE on Log(CPI) do not work? So I have to back-transform it to normal CPI?